# Que Tipos de dados PostGis são esses

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, postgis

Na documentação do Postgis 2.3 na parte 4.2 PostGIS Geography Type, é mencionado que os seguintes tipos são suportados.

- `POINT`
- `LINESTRING`
- `POLYGON`
- `MULTIPOINT`
- `MULTILINESTRING`
- `MULTIPOLYGON`
- `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION`

Porém em outros lugares vejo escrito sobre `ST_CircularString`, `POLYHEDRALSURFACE` e etc, enfim que valores são esses?

Answer (score 0):

`POLYHEDRALSURFACE` nada mais são do que superfícies poliédricas, geralmente em três dimensões, que  são compostas de vértices, arestas, facetas e uma relação de incidência sobre elas.

`SELECT ST_AsEWKT(ST_GeometryN(p_geom,3)) As geom_ewkt FROM (SELECT ST_GeomFromEWKT('POLYHEDRALSURFACE(((0 0 0, 0 0 1, 0 1 1, 0 1 0, 0 0 0)),((0 0 0, 0 1 0, 1 1 0, 1 0 0, 0 0 0)),((0 0 0, 1 0 0, 1 0 1, 0 0 1, 0 0 0)),((1 1 0, 1 1 1, 1 0 1, 1 0 0, 1 1 0)),((0 1 0, 0 1 1, 1 1 1, 1 1 0, 0 1 0)),((0 0 1, 1 0 1, 1 1 1, 0 1 1, 0 0 1))
)')  AS p_geom )  AS a;geom_ewkt
 POLYGON((0 0 0,1 0 0,1 0 1,0 0 1,0 0 0))`

ou

`SELECT ST_AsEWKT(ST_GeometryN(geom,2)) as wkt FROM (SELECT ST_GeomFromEWKT('TIN (((0 0 0,0 0 1,0 1 0,0 0 0)), ((0 0 0,0 1 0,1 1 0,0 0 0)))')  AS geom) AS g; wkt
 TRIANGLE((0 0 0,0 1 0,1 1 0,0 0 0))`

Já `ST_CircularString` é um subtipo de `ST_Curve` que usa segmentos de linha circulares entre os pontos de controle.